script to convert Times from Military to 12-hr in google sheets? (complex cells)
I have a schedule exported from another source that has schedules in military format, trying to reformat to 12-h.  The shift details are start - end in the cell.  Need some help with a script that will reformat the times to 12-h formatting.
Here is the basic layout of the sheet...  Thanks for any assistance!



Name
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday




person 1
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00
16:00 - 00:00
16:00 - 00:00
NO SHIFT


person 2
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
06:45 - 16:00
NO SHIFT
08:00 - 16:00
08:00 - 16:00


person 3
16:00 - 00:00
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT


person 4
16:00 - 23:00
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00


person 5
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 22:00
NO SHIFT


person 6
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
06:45 - 16:00
06:45 - 16:00
NO SHIFT


person 7
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 22:00


person 8
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00
16:00 - 00:00
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00


person 9
NO SHIFT
06:45 - 16:00
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
06:45 - 16:00


person 10
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00
16:00 - 00:00
NO SHIFT
NO SHIFT
16:00 - 00:00
NO SHIFT



tried a macro with find / replace, but it seems to not have recorded the steps properly

You can use the TEXT function with "hh:mm AM/PM" format:
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(B2:H11,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="NO SHIFT",x,JOIN(" - ",TEXT(SPLIT(x,"-"),"hh:mm AM/PM"))))))


Then copy the resulting table and Paste special > Values only on the original table.

That could work, but I really would prefer a script that reformats rather than having to manually copy & paste multiple times & referencing specific cells.  The row counts might change from week to week, so to build it in & have to change each week might be cumbersome.  I'll give it a go for now.

I pasted the "data" on a separate sheet, then used the formula to reference the other sheet.  Worked ok, but if I expand to 99 rows so it incorporates any # of entries, I get "#VALUE"  in the rows without info.  is there a solution to filter that out when it receives no info?

you can simply put an IFERROR around the formula.

=iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(Data!A1:H99,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="NO SHIFT",x,JOIN(" -"&Char(10),TEXT(SPLIT(x,"-"),"h:mm AM/PM")))))))

Ended up using this line as the formula.  I chose to put a line break ( &Char(10) ) before the ending shift time & incorporated the IFERROR as suggested.
Thank you Z for responding so quickly!
